# Get concise email header Outlook Mailitem VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, email-headers, mailitem

I am catching the outlook mailItem after its being sent. I would like to get the email header i.e. To, From, CC, Subject, Body etc. I have tried using

```
Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
tempVar = Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
                MsgBox(tempVar)
```

but that returns the whole header. Is there a way to get concise header information instead of trying to parse the string returned from the PropertyAccessor using PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you neeed to use the trasport headers?

Instead, you can get all property values using the Outlook object model. Take a look at the corresponding properties of the MailItem class: [To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378(v=office.15).aspx), [CC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869030(v=office.15).aspx), [Recipients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320(v=office.15).aspx), [Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: Yes I can but I was wondering if there was any other way to get all the email header information.

Comment: There is no other way.